# Run NestJs with Docker container

Tags: docker, nestjs

I use these NestJs for education [GITHUB](https://github.com/brocoders/nestjs-boilerplate.git), but I can't run it from the Docker file, gives me an error.I had checked with cli inside /usr/src/app/package.json and the start:prod script was there. Where is the problem?

```
/usr/bin/env: 'bash\r': No such file or directory

"[37;40mnpm ERR! Missing script: "start:prod

    npm ERR! 
    
    npm ERR! Did you mean this?
    
    npm ERR!     npm run start:prod # run the "start:prod" package script
    
    npm ERR! 
    
    npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
    
    npm ERR!   npm run
    
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    
    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-07-20T12_20_18_944Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked just fine
`docker-compose --env-file env-example -p ci up --build`

```
.
.
.
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] UsersController {/api/users} (version: 1): +192ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/users, POST} (version: 1) route +3ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/users, GET} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/users/:id, GET} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/users/:id, PATCH} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/users/:id, DELETE} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] FilesController {/api/files} (version: 1): +0ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/files/upload, POST} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/files/:path, GET} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AuthController {/api/auth} (version: 1): +0ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/email/login, POST} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/admin/email/login, POST} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/email/register, POST} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/email/confirm, POST} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/forgot/password, POST} (version: 1) route +0ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/reset/password, POST} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/me, GET} (version: 1) route +0ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/me, PATCH} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/me, DELETE} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AuthFacebookController {/api/auth/facebook} (version: 1): +0ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/facebook/login, POST} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AuthGoogleController {/api/auth/google} (version: 1): +0ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/google/login, POST} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AuthTwitterController {/api/auth/twitter} (version: 1): +0ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/twitter/login, POST} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AuthAppleController {/api/auth/apple} (version: 1): +0ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/auth/apple/login, POST} (version: 1) route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] HomeController {/api}: +0ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +1ms
api_1       | [Nest] 129  - 07/21/2022, 5:38:15 AM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +8ms
```

Comment: Good but I still have "pi_1       | npm ERR! Missing script: "start:prod
api_1       | npm ERR!
api_1       | npm ERR! Did you mean this?
api_1       | npm ERR!     npm run start:prod # run the "start:prod" package script
api_1       | npm ERR!
api_1       | npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
api_1       | npm ERR!   npm run
api_1       |
api_1       | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
api_1       | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-07-21T07_49_46_678Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Also, I have a question if the .env file is copied each time on the container run how can I pass paramaters

Comment: Can you share command you are using to start the services. As for passing env file, look at the command i have used. `docker-compose --env-file env-example -p ci up --build`